# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, web-config

I am getting this Kind of Error like::

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: site

while Debugging any of my Project.

I have also tried after Reinstalling My Visual Studio 2012. But again the same kind of problem I am getting while Debugging.

My System's Configurations are :

- Windows 8 : 32-bit
- Visual Studio : 2012

Exception is thrown at the time of Showing Web Page Like,

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +298

[HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: where this exception is thrown?

Comment: Exception is thrown while showing the Web Page after Debugging.

Comment: Not clear post some code which line this exception is thrown

Comment: Now see I have also Given the Error shown while showing the Web Page

Comment: @Rahul_RJ You are not helping. You are showing the stack trace where it says the location of the exception but not including that code.

Comment: @Rahul_RJ post which point in your code exactly throws exception

Comment: No there are no Exceptions at the Time of Rebuild, But after Debugging only this Error is shown on the Browser

Comment: Windows 10 updated this morning caused this issue for me. I'm glad I found your question :)

Answer (score 533, accepted):

If using IIS:

- control panel
- Programs
- open or close windows features
- tick internet information services
- then restart your visual studio

If using IIS Express:

Open 'Add/Remove Programs' from the old control panel and run a repair on IIS Express
Or you might go **Control Panel** ->> **Programs** ->> **Programs and Features** ->> **Turn Windows features on or off** ->> **Internet Information Services**
and check the checkbox as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Worked well. Visual Studio should have tell that straight forward. IIS is not enabled. Thanks Man

Comment: Thank you, it worket for me too. Why IIS Express needs IIS installed? I don't understand that. I use default web.config, nothing special.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I recently encountered this error. With me, the fault was that I was trying to run 2 different websites in 2 different visual studio solutions. I think IIS Express only allows for 1 concurrent visual studio solution to run at once. So, when you need to have 2 solutions active on IIS, you need to enable IIS using the windows features. If not, you just have to make sure there's only one solution running on IIS Express at any given time.

Comment: Same as Tsasken, I just got it a bit earlier today. Thanks to MustafaP for the answer and in general to Stackoverflow and associated sites for the help I've had!!! fixed the prob in 30 min since it popped up.

Comment: After a Windows-update this issue got me. Solution still works today! Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Build 16199.rs_prerelease.170513-2252

Comment: You don't need *all* of IIS, you can just install IIS Management Console (IIS --> Web Management Tools --> IIS Management Console).

Comment: I also received this error after updating to 'Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Build 16199.rs_prerelease.170513-2252'. Added 'IIS Management Console' as recommended by JPD. Problem solved.

Comment: Crazy! This question was asked 4 years ago and the issue resurfaced again in Insider Preview Build

Comment: Just had this issue on Insider Preview Build 16257.rs3_release.170728-1700 so it is still occurring!

Comment: Got it with Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview 
Evaluation copy. Build 16281.rs3 release.17D82g-1438. Thank for this solution. I also only installed the IIS Management Console.

Comment: Got the error with the Win10 Fall creators update, installing only the "Hostable Web Core" did the trick. Thanks ;)

Comment: GOD DAMN YOU MICROSOFT 
GOD BLESS YOU GUYS

Comment: After updating to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, repairing IIS Express sorted my issue. Many thanks!

Comment: 4 years later and the answer still holds up.  Windows 10 Update installed and IIS went away.  Seriously, WTF MS...

Comment: Solution still works for Windows 10, version 1709 (OS Build 16299.64)

Comment: Didn't have to restart VS

Comment: Repair IISExpress fixed this for me too after Fall Creators Update.

Comment: lovely, system update screwed me too :) lack of coffee made me just google the exception and I'm glad I did as I would have never thought of IIS being the issue !

Comment: 5 Years later, and still the same issue (and solution), Windows Automatic Update and BOOM

Comment: I really think that Microsoft has a few old people collecting fat paychecks and stuff like these are run by bunch of students and interns. How the hell can this happen.

Comment: Still holds true. Faced this error after running a Windows update.

Comment: Happened to me too after a Windows up with IIS Express. 
I had to install the windows feature 'IIS Hostable Web Core' in order to fix the issue. Merely reparing/uninstall/install/combinations didn't fix it. But installing the windows feature seems to "repair" IIS Express.

Comment: I always faced same issue after updating my Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Just an FYI; I received a Windows Update this morning, and thereafter I had this issue. As others have suggested, using the Repair option Control Panel still works. In my case, I ran a repair on the program titled "IIS 10.0 Express".

Comment: 2018 here - windows 10 pushed an update out last night.  This problem came to be.  This solution still worked. Thank you.

Comment: I upgraded my windows and had the same problem. The answer is still valid!

Comment: -1 Despite being an old answer, it would be better to specify which options to turn on, as the _tick_, being a square, means that only some options are active, and not all. In order to prevent turning on something we don't want, security reasons for instance, it would be better if someone could supply the full tree of active options.

Comment: Thank you for this, it actually solved my issue right away. Regardless, it's worth noting that if you use localhost alongside other frameworks and programs, **port 80 will be blocked by IIS**.

Comment: Enabling IIS Express and restarting didn't work for me.  Tried the repair option and Windows refused to do it.  Downloaded the Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter as described here: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/cannot-install-uninstall-programs-windows-7 and uninstalled IIS Express.  Then downloaded IIS Express and re-installed.  Then it worked.  Surprising how often tasks that should take minutes take hours when Microsoft products are involved.

Comment: I'm using IIS and this method is solved my above issue. Thank you

Comment: @ZahidRiaz have you ever seen the error in which Visual Studio says: "Catastrofic Failure." and closes itself? You might think the world would end after this message, but you then just reopen VS and everything is nice again.

Answer (score 166):

This occurred to me when I applied the 2017 Fall Creator Update.  I was able to resolve by repairing IIS 10.0 Express (I do *not* have IIS installed on my box.)

**Note:** As a user pointed out in the comments,

> Repair can be found in "Programs and Features" - the "classic" control panel.

Comment: Repair can be found in "Programs and Features" - the "classic" control panel.

Comment: Same here! Repairing IIS 10.0 Express fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This is the solution for IIS Express, works as explained.  Since we cannot have two official answers, I have added this to the official answer.

Comment: Repairing IIS Express would crash the installer for me. I had to uninstall/re-install IIS Express using the Visual Studio 2017 installer under the individual components section. It will tell you other components need to be uninstalled as well. Make note of them and and then proceed with uninstall/re-install of the components.

Comment: I ended up downloading the stand-alone installer for IIS 10.0 Express and doing the uninstall/re-install using that instead of letting the VS installer removed the other things. Everything seems to be working out so far.

Comment: Don't you think it's completely ridiculous that you have two interfaces for Add/Remove programs in one system and they have different features (you can't repair from "new" one)?

Comment: Make sure you shut down IIS Express before you repair it. Right-click the icon in the notification area and click Exit. Repairing IIS Express while it's running won't show any error, but it will not fix the issue either.

Comment: Installed the Creators Update somewhat late, on 2018-01-24 and this happened. It actually seems to have removed IIS Express. I would certainly call this a breaking change. Why is it still part of their release?

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks!

Comment: Classic "Programs and features" can be started by typing appwiz.cpl in start menu

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue i resolved it by repairing the iis server in programs and features.

**GO TO**

*Controll panel > uninstall a program 
and then right click the installed iis express server (installed with Visual Studio)
and then click repair.*

this is how i solved this issue

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue with VS2017. Following solved the issue.

1. Run Command prompt as Administrator.
2. Write following two commands which will update your registry.

> reg add HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp /v MajorVersion /t
>   REG_DWORD /d 10 /f
>
> reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\InetStp /v MajorVersion /t REG_DWORD
>   /d 10 /f

This should solve your problem. Refer to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/59516/vs-2017-152-cant-debug-aspnet-projects.html) for more details.

Comment: This solution worked for me when I was blocked by a grayed out Modify button in Control Panel add/remove programs.

Comment: you the man, microsoft f*cked up with its falls creator update sh*t, you fixed it. you worth more than the entire company

Comment: This fixed it for me - vanilla install of Visual Studio 2019 in Windows Server 2019. Didn't need a reboot.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of installing the bloated IIS, I get mine resolved by installing Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core from the Windows Features

Comment: You don't have to install *all* of IIS - just tick the box and take the defaults. Making sure that's clear :)

Comment: Got the error with the Win10 Fall creators update, installing only the "Hostable Web Core" did the trick. Thanks ;)

Comment: I can confirm also that following the Win10 Fall creators update, the above suggested solution of installing the Hostable Web core component did the trick. To do this click on the Microsoft Windows button, then type Turn Windows Features ON or OFF in  the search box, then select Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core.

Comment: Best Solution. Worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

When you start with a Specific Page while debugging your project, and you are using Local IIS, 
you might have filled a wrong value in the Specific Page textbox.

(via Project Properties > Web > Start Action > Specific Page)

Wrong configuration:

```
Specific Page: "http://localhost/MyApplication/Start/SpecificPage.aspx"
Project Url: "http://localhost/MyApplication"
```

Right configuration:

```
Specific Page: "/Start/SpecificPage.aspx"
Project Url: "http://localhost/MyApplication"
```

Note: Ignore the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with using the built in Visual Studio Development server or you don't want to or cannot install IIS, you can change the web server the project uses by going into

1. > Project Properties (right click project in solution explorer and select properties)
2. > select Web tab
3. > select "Use Visual Studio Development Server".

I don't know how it happened to me, but somehow this option was changed to "Use Local IIS Web Server" for one of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

This resolved the issue on Windows 10 after the last update

go Control Panel ->> Programs ->> Programs and Features ->> Turn Windows features on or off ->> Internet Information Services

But based on previous response it doesn't work unless checking all these options as on pic below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was happening because I had switched over to "Run as Administrator". Just one instance of VS was running, but running it as admin threw this error. Switching back fixed me right up.

Answer (score 0):

Modify was greyed out for me, but adding the IIS Management Console under programs and features fixed this for me. Also on Windows 10 fall update.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when trying to run a project targeting Framework 4.5 in VS2017. After changing it to Framework 4.6.X it got fixed by itself.

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features and repair the IIS Express.
- Restart the visual studio.

To turn on the IIS is not recommended as other comments suggests if you are not using your system as a live server. For development purpose only IIS Express is adequate.