# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values (Parameter name: site)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just started working with asp.net mvc 4. I've created this simple controller class and did this small coding but when i run my project it throw an error. I don't know what this error is and how to fix it. please help me with it.

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

> when i run the application on google chrome it throw the follwoing error
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: site
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: site
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: site]
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.> 
>   Parameter name: site]
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9951956
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248**

Comment: You have some routes defined by you?

Comment: did you define a parameter named `site` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @LiranBo No, that is the only lines of code I used in my coding.

Answer (score 2):

This Should Solved the problem

go

- Control Panel
- Programs and Features
- Turn Windows Features on or off
- tick Internet Information Services
- then Restart your Laptop

It worked for me

I found that [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: i that case, other programmers with similar problems would have to wait till i get enough reputation? good

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your Action signature. Since, the Index is a default action defined in `RegisterRoutes` so it would be invoked as soon as you launch the site. Since MVC excepts the return type of `ActionResult` and throws exception if does not find in invoked action. You can change the return type to `ActionResult` and wrap the return value in Json if the value return is excepted of type string.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.Json(typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your code but the problem is still there, still showing the same error.