# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site - Error Due To Creators Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

After a installing the creators update I ended up getting this error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site error.
```

I was able to repair IIS by downloading IIS 10 from Microsoft. Unfortunately, in addition to breaking IIS the Creators update borked my user permissions on my dev folders and git was unable to add and remove folders. For the life of me I couldn't figure out how to fix that. So, I decided to roll windows back.

Guess what? It broke IIS again. This time though the IIS 10 installer would not let me repair IIS, I couldn't repair it from Add/Remove programs, and I can't uninstall it to start over. I tried uninstalling it from the VS2017 installer and reinstalling it that also did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found these SO questions:

[Specified Argument was out of the range of valid values Parameter name : site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034455/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

[Specified argument was out of the range of valid values (Parameter name: site)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412229/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

[Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

None of the accepted answers fixed my error, on the third SO post I found what saved me. I don't have enough rep to comment but I wanted to share this in case anyone else runs into this extremely frustrating bug.

From [Sikandar Amla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2335620/sikandar-amla)'s answer:

I had the same issue with VS2017. Following solved the issue.

1. Run Command prompt as Administrator.
2. Write following two commands which will update your registry.

   reg add HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp /v MajorVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 10 /f

   reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\InetStp /v MajorVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 10 /f

This should solve your problem. Refer to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/59516/vs-2017-152-cant-debug-aspnet-projects.html) for more details.

Comment: How is it different from [@SikandarAmla answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222884/1997232)? *"I don't have enough rep to comment"* is not a valid to reason to: a) ask duplicate question b) self-answer with duplicate answer.