# Inconsistent response from the WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that is hosted in IIS7, this service is just a wrapper of another service, so what it does it calls the actual service then return a response which is then passed on to the client. The issue that I'm having is that I send a request and it returns data, when I send another request with the second then I get the below error: Please will you share some light on what could be a problem here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.<br>Parameter name: value</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      pre { width: 280px; }
     }
   </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/VendorSelfCarewebapi' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.<br>Parameter name: value</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">
           <b> Description: </b>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
        <br><br>

        <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.<br>Parameter name: value<br><br>

        <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code>An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>
        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                <code><pre>
                [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
                Parameter name: value]
                 System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusDescription(String value) +3165151
                 System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusDescription(String value) +9
                 System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.CopyResponseStatusAndHeaders(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, HttpResponseMessage response) +53
                 System.Web.Http.WebHost.&lt;ConvertResponse&gt;d__6.MoveNext() +96
                 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
                 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
                 System.Web.Http.WebHost.&lt;ProcessRequestAsyncCore&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +381
                 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
                 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
                 System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +60
                 System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
                 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651516
                 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +155
                </pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

        </font>

</body>
</html>

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException]: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusDescription(String value)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusDescription(String value)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.CopyResponseStatusAndHeaders(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, HttpResponseMessage response)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<ConvertResponse>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Instead of pasting the contents of the error page, post the *code* that generated the exception. Try debugging your code, add exception handling to log any exceptions. Since the call stack contains `TaskAwaiter` it's very likely an error occured in an asynchronous method that didn't have an exception handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a REST service? A SOAP service??
I think that you're not handling the exception in the service, so you're getting the default response from IIS, which is a web page.

You should handle the exception in the service and return an object (or XML) containing the exception details.

If it's an invocation error, you should try to custom handle incoming requests on the service.

Or maybe this could help [Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.