# Nuget Error:Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: supportedFrameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to install a nuget package`Asp.Net WebAPI 2` using nuget package manager.

I get this error :

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: supportedFrameworks
```

[image]

I follow this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site` but no result.I have uninstalled the visual studio and installed that again but no result.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally installed VS 2015.that it has asp.net webapi2 by default.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when using visual Studio 2013 and couldn't install any Nuget package.
 To solve it please follow these steps :

- Go to this folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable",
  you'll find these 3 folders

  v4.0, v4.6, v4.5

rename or delete them. 
Then go to the Control Panel --> unistall a programme --> Select Visual Studio and click repair.

Your Visual studio shall work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Fully reinstalling Visual Studio 2012 Express for WEB solved it for me.