# Specified Argument was out of the range of valid values Parameter name : site

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Using Visual Studio 2015, with Windows 10 hp laptop. After I created an asp.net mvc application, build it and run it I get this error:

> Specified Argument was out of the range of valid values Parameter name : site
>   Description : An unhanded Exception occurred during the execution of  the current web request
>   Stack Trace:
>   [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified Argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter Name: site]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags, hostingFlags, PolicyLevel, policylevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +560
>   [HttpException (0x80004005): Specified Argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter Name: site]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +765
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerReuest wr, HttpContext context) +195

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show the code that throws this exception. Without code, there is no way someone could tell the reason for this error.

Comment: this error occurs on start up, i don't think its a code related problem

Comment: Victor, I had the exact same problem and of course there is no code to show. But the problem is solved by your answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

This Solved the problem

go

- Control Panel
- Programs and Features
- Turn Windows Features on or off
- tick Internet Information Services
- then Restart Laptop

It worked for me

I found that [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

Comment: That is considering the OT has admin rights on the machine and it is possible to just go ahead and install IIS. I have the same issue but i cannot install IIS, we only use IISExpress, which should be OK.

Comment: Thank you for this, it actually solved my issue right away. Regardless, it's worth noting that if you use localhost alongside other frameworks and programs, **port 80 will be blocked by IIS**.