# IISExpress ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Parameter name: site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

When I create a simple website in **VS2015** (webforms/MVC doesn't matter) and run it using **IISExpress**, I get the following exception:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range
>   of valid values. Parameter name: site]

This question has come up before notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034455/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site) and the solution identified is to enable IIS in Windows control panel.  I'm using a corporate machine that's locked down, so I can't easily do this.  Before I go through the process to get it enabled, I was hoping to better understand the reasoning behind this fix.  Shouldn't IISExpress work without IIS?  And are there any other fixes/workarounds?

UPDATE: I'm on Windows 7, using IISExpress 10.

Comment: How was IISExpress installed? Are you certain that it is enabled?

Comment: It was installed with Visual Studio, I assume.  In any case it's definitely there and running.  For example, I tried leaving VS closed and launching iisexpress.exe from the command line, to see if that would make a difference.  Still got the same error when trying to load an aspx page.  Interestingly enough, iisexpress will serve a plain HTML page with no issue though (this is true whether launching from VS or the command line).

Comment: Look at your projects Property Pages -> Start Options

Comment: Ok, what am I looking for there?  The project is already configured to run on IISExpress.

Comment: Sorry, If that looks fine to you, then I think I have no further suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by doing the steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352322/64279

Apparently IIS Express, has some dependencies on IIS.