# Can't run any ASP.net MVC app after installing Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

After installing Windows 10 Fall Creators Update I can't run any web app using Visual Studio 15.4.0 with IISExpress.

Even creating a new project does not run.

The error (some words in spanish, but it's an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for the `site` parameter) :

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
Nombre del parámetro: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +280

[HttpException (0x80004005): El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
Nombre del parámetro: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10042604
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.7.2556.0
```

Tried rebooting, cleaning, etc, but nothing works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you send the errors in English

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi It's an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site

Answer (score 13):

The @rene question was the solution:

- Go to control panel
- Programs
- Open or close windows features
- Tick internet information services
- Restart

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving this problem, it helped me a lot

Comment: I'm now trying to figure out if I never had IIS installed or if the latest update switched it off.

Comment: @GlennFerrie I didn't even knew that I need IIS to run IISExpress

Comment: Seems like there are some system settings that VS is relying on -- I haven't pinned it down yet, but this fixed my issue.

Comment: If you use IIS Express, and not IIS, then the fix is to repair IIS Express under Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features

Comment: For me, it was not ticked before but ticking it now fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar error after reinstalling VS without all the packages. Try installing all the prerequisites that are needed for your MVC. In my case it was TypeScrypt 2.0 and PowerShell tools. Hope this helps.