# The properties page issue VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

On xamarin PCL solution on the Droid project's properties i am getting this error :
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: API level not recognized: 23

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23519/anyone-experienced-this-xamarin-studio-layout-editor-error-message)  and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site)

Comment: Maybe you need remove all components of API level 23.

Comment: I will try the second solution. i came across those solutions but they are a bit far from my case. Also i saw the time when they had the issue and i am in 2018 and get the latest version of the xamarin i was wondering how such a big platform couldnt resolve this since 2014

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the AndroidSDK resolved the issue. 
For similar issue you can remove the Api giving the issue but i still believe Microsoft has to do something about this.