# Running Web Api gives specified argument was out of the range of valid values exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created new web api while it gives following following error.

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +280

[HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10043436
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

when i run the same code in another system it works correctly.I am using windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable your IIS in your control panel >> Programs & Features?

Comment: You can check this thread for more infromations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772216/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-site

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by uninstalling ISS 10.0 express and reinstalling ISS 8.0 express