# IIS returns 504 Sometimes, to the exact same request (MVC4 ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, http-status-code-504

5 on Windows Server 2008R2 with ASP.Net MVC4

occasionally i'm receiving 504 status from the IIS to an exact request (sometimes everything is ok and i'm receiving 200)

When debugging the server, the request itself comes with an empty body but with proper content length header (not 0), the weird thing is that i can see in fiddler the actual body (an xml with 40,000 characters), so it is surely not a client problem.

Also I've noticed that when i'm receiving 504, it takes a lot of time until it reaches my handler

i'm trying to figure out why the IIS "clips" the body from my request?

Comment: Check this thread to see how to display detailed error information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552534/how-to-see-specific-error-information-when-server-throws-server-error-in-ap. This might give you some feedback on what the error is.