# Asp.Net Dropdown onchange Event Not Working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my company want to modify one ASp.net Project,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drdIssuer" runat="server" CssClass="txtfield" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="showvalues();">
                    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is html asp code,And JAvascript like this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function showvalues()
       {
           alert('Yes');
       }
       </script>
```

When I change dropdown listing I want to work showvalues() function how do i do it,Can you guys help me....

Comment: did you added the basic jquery library for this. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`. I tried your code in my page and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes,I added in that page,I got the error Server Error in '/' Application.

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged'   Can You help me thiserror..

Comment: can you show the code behind of `'drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: There is no code inside that,,

Comment: protected void drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
    }

Comment: Is there any other code in this page?? paste it here http://jsfiddle.net/ and give me the link. Coz, I have written the same page and it is not giving me any error

Comment: I tried here it is working..

Comment: protected void drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
          SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
            if (drdIssuer.SelectedValue == "Val1")
            {
               Response.Write(@"<script langauge='text/javascript'>alert('...Alert Goes here...');</script>");
            } 
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can register a html event for the select element that is rendered by the asp:dropdown.

```
drdIssuer.Attributes["onchange"] = "showvalues();";
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You are getting that error because, you have might not added the namespace

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

2. Also as mentioned by you in the comment that you are getting the error as

> I got the error Server Error in '/' Application

For that you may go for a detailed solution mentioned at [Geeks blogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx).

And also have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063190/how-to-resolve-server-error-in-application-error) As, it is not a major issue and as per the information provided by you, the above solution should work.

Your whole code-behind for the `drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged` should look like this

```
using System.Data.SqlClient; //namespace


protected void drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
     SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
     if (drdIssuer.SelectedValue == "Val1")
     {
         Response.Write(@"<script langauge='text/javascript'>alert('...Alert Goes here...');</script>");
     }
 }
```

Also if you remove the `onChange` function from the values. Your `Response.Write` will also work for `Val1`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drdIssuer" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drdIssuer_SelectedIndexChanged"
        CssClass="txtfield" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Val1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Val2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Val3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Val4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Hope that helps.