# Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2146232576

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please help me!I can't find any solution for this issue

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

> The compiler failed with error code -2146232576.

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\Workpaces\sagote.com\Wedding\3\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\47011476\00fbf29a_4bc5d201\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\3e4699ee\00d223f3_984fd201\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\e44922d6\00ae0f0a_9e10ce01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\3e9cfada\000ff382_10aece01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\a72ce407\005b39b8_5fcbcc01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\2d479306\00e7c43f_4550d201\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\eeb7a29f\004382d7_743ad001\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\74e8ab62\0088f21e_984fd201\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\aeb27190\0003c034_e94ad201\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\fdddc2aa\00363de7_0227cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\85c04ee5\009fcac3_4450d201\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\c3f718db\0049d671_4550d201\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\3aa08bcf\0049d671_4550d201\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\82f865b1\e2cbec79_ab28d301\Wedding.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\30e0ddbb\007adf92_1fafcf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\62bfafb1\004382d7_743ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\8bc985a8\00d3499e_743ad001\System.Web.Http.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\9b54a075\004382d7_743ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\5019bd9c\00c52297_743ad001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\3abcf35d\00e42c91_743ad001\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\a1484cf3\004382d7_743ad001\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\4186b1dd\00a9d488_743ad001\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\assembly\dl3\d4271259\006548bd_743ad001\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\App_global.asax.whx-i4h_.dll" /debug- /optimize+ /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\App_global.asax.whx-i4h_.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f9ae3e7\fb951622\App_global.asax.whx-i4h_.1.cs"`

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34209

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063190/how-to-resolve-server-error-in-application-error) this is what you should do:

You may get this error when trying to browse an asp.net application.

The debug information shows that "This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

However, this error occurs primarily out of 2 scenarios.

- When you create an new web application using visual studio.net, it automatically creates the virtual directory and configures it as an application. However, if you manually create the virtual directory and it is not configured as an application, then you will not be able to browse the application and may get the above error. The debug information you get as mentioned above, is applicable to this scenario.

To resolve it, Right Click on the virtual directory - select properties and then click on "Create" next to the "Application" Label and the textbox. It will automatically create the "application" using the virtual directory's name. Now the application can be accessed.

- When you have sub-directories in your application, you can have web.config file for the sub-directory. However, there are certain properties which cannot be set in the web.config of the sub-directory such as authentication, session state (you may see that the error message shows the line number where the authentication or sessionstate is declared in the web.config of the sub-directory). The reason is, these settings cannot be overridden at the sub-directory level unless the sub-directory is also configured as an application (as mentioned in the above point).

Mostly we have the practice of adding web.config in the sub-directory if we want to protect access to the sub-directory files (say, the directory is admin and we wish to protect the admin pages from unathorized users).

Answer (score 9):

@napi15's solutions is good and I voted for it. However, simply clicking on the project properties' web tab, and pressing the "Create Virtual Directory" button fixed the issue for us in about 30 seconds.

Comment: "All Roads Lead to Rome."

Comment: This also solved my issue and was much clearer too.

Answer (score 2):

try these steps:

- delete the bin and obj folder in your source project
- delete the bin folder on your destination server
- build and publish your application

Comment: This also worked for me. People should rather try this first before trying the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I updated Visual studio 2017 to the latest version.
My project is a WebForm type and It stopped working with the error above after I updated the Nuget packages.

I spent hours searching for solution to this but none works. 
The issue with Webform is that you cannot find a place to update the Virtual Directory unlike before. I realized that feature has been removed.

**The solution** that helped me was painful but quite easy. I simply added a new WebForm project to my solution and migrated the code.

Note: I noticed a few changes to the default WebForm template created by Visual studio:

- App_Code folder has been eliminated. I was now able to place my classes in my custom Helper folder.
- .cs files now have a third component visible.
- General .cs class files and WebForm class files are now braced with the namespace.

So you have to take good note of the features while migrating the codes.

Lastly, do not forget to visit your App_Start/Route_Config  file and change Redirect to Off if you're using Page Methods

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in another post, removing below given lines helped me to resolve the issue. I am still looking for a solution which can work without removing these lines

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```