# How to read txt file in c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey guys i need to solve this problem and I am completely lost.

1. In root application create txt file, for example addresses.txt a in there will be dates in format: Name;Path;number_of_days;

2: In method Index load this .txt, where could be 10 rows with addresses. I need to load every row with string.Split separator will be semicolon(;)
This will be load to List object. Then it will go through the foreach and you will go through the individual addresses via File.Getfiles(), where the input parameter is the directory.
your files will be loaded, which you pass and if neither of them is younger than number_of_days, you note the error for this entry

Comment: Try google for 'c# how to read/write text files' and you find many examples. Don't expect to get some code made for you when you post a description on what needs to be done. People here have a job to do and you need to do your home work first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to read a `.txt` file from the root folder:

```
    public string LoadTextFile()
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string myTxtFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/addresses.txt");
            if (File.Exists(myTxtFile))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myTxtFile))
                {
                    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    response = content;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response = "File not found, error msg :" + myTxtFile;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response= "Error in getting function LoadTextFile, Error msg :" + ex.Message;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Your `response` string will contain the contents from the file that is read.

Comment: its giving me this "Server Error in '/' Application". and under that it write the content  of the file

Comment: @Dan Put a break-point when you invoke the method to see if you are getting any errors. Also where are you placing your file?

Comment: in a root of application

Comment: Ok, then it should read the file: `addresses.txt`. What error are you getting?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application

Comment: @Dan You can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063190/how-to-resolve-server-error-in-application-error . You should also set `debug` in your web.config to true: `<compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="true" />`

Comment: @dan Did it work ?

Comment: No it did not :(

Comment: it didnt help sorry, but thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Try debugging this: is it this particular method that gives the error, or your own code that *calls* this method? If you see the file contents, then I would assume it is *your* code (invisible to us) that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var fileContents = 
    System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.txt"));
```